# Сложности с do while php

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться вот в чем:
Есть выпадающее меню (категории - подкатегории) содержимое которого выводится из БД. Из одной таблицы выводятся "категории" меню из второй таблицы "подкатегории" соответствующие нужной категории. Суть проблемы: я не могу понять где ошибка в коде, сейчас выводятся все категории, но подкатегория выводится только одна и она одинаковая для всех категорий.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category_db $qury_start_num",$link);
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM type_tovar_db WHERE type_category='Vodonagrevateli' ",$link);
If (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0 & mysql_num_rows($result3) > 0) {

    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);

    do {
       echo '
       <li>
           <a href="#">'.$row2["name_category_tovar"].'</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
               <li>
                    <a href="#">'.$row3["name_type_tovar"].'</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       ';
    } while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
}
```

Comment: это, случайно, не подкатегория `'Vodonagrevateli'`?

Comment: Сразу сюда, памагитии, не разобрался в своем же коде, даже не отформатировал в соответствующий вид. Предыдущий коммент тебе в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

`$row3` получается только 1 раз и не перебирается в цикле. Соответственно и выводится одно и то же

Comment: А как указать в одном цикле переборку 2х переменных? В моем случае row2 и row3

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/447617)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica а что же это, если не ответ на вопрос _Суть проблемы: я не могу понять где ошибка в коде, сейчас выводятся все категории, но подкатегория выводится только одна и она одинаковая для всех категорий_? )))

Comment: Извините, я когда проверяю в очередях, не рассматриваю все вопросы.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica А как тогда принимать решение что является ответом на вопрос, а что нет, если не ознакомиться перед этим с вопросом и ответами которые ранее давались на этот вопрос(если они уже есть конечно)?

Comment: Там есть пункт: "выглядит нормально". Это значит, что ответ может и на самом деле плох, но выглядит нормально: есть код, текст, примеры и т.д. Пусть даже код и не работает, все равно выглядит нормально — не каждый проверяющий должен знать :то ли это на самом деле или нет. Ну а если ответ — одна строчка, то скорее всего это не ответ, а коммент.  Хотя бывают исключения — вот это например. Нo это спорный случай, я все равно считаю ,что это не ответ.

Comment: _не каждый проверяющий должен знать_ для сомневающихся, есть кнопочка "пропустить")))